# Json data into Java REST service causing 500 error

Tags: java, ajax, rest, post

I am trying to send a List of JSON objects into a post request. I keep getting a 500 error here. I feel like i am not setting up my variable in the Method definiton to the right data type but im not sure what it should be set too.

AJAX Request:

```
function post_request(json_data) {

    $j.ajax({
        url : '../api/createDisplayGroup/postHtmlVar/' + containerID[1] + '/' + containerType[1],
        data: JSON.stringify(json_data),
        dataType: 'json',
        type : 'post',
        contentType : 'application/json'
    }).done(function(response) {
        run_update(response);
    }).error(function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error getting request');
    });
};
```

Java REST Service (POST only):

```
@POST
 @Path("/postHtmlVar/{containerId}/{contentType}")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<TabDefinition> postHtml(@PathParam("containerId") String containerId, @PathParam("contentType") String contentType, List<JSONObject> displayGroups) {
     Long contId = Long.parseLong(containerId);
     Long contType = Long.parseLong(contentType);


     //return convertToResponse(peopleFilterService.getDisplayGroups(contId, contType));*/

     return testDisplayGroup();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the input json string as a `@FormDataParam`. I don't think your JAVA REST framework can marshal the json to a list of JSONObject. You may have to create a class representing the json data and define your method like this:

```
public List<TabDefinition> postHtml(@PathParam("containerId") String containerId, @PathParam("contentType") String contentType, @FormDataParam MyJSonDataClass myJsonDataClassObj) {
```

Comment: maybe i dont understand the @FormDataParam completely but if i understand it correctly that will allow me to grab data out of form fields.

What i need to do is get my entire array of json objects from the front end into the rest service. Is it possible to use JSON.stringify(jsonArray) and assign that string to a "hidden" form variable?

Comment: @Deslyxia FormDataParam is to read the params from the POST body.

Comment: And will i be consuming multipart/form-data at this point instead of application/json?